# What is a proper way to deal with parallel protractor(selenium) tests not interfering with each other's data?

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, protractor, automated-tests

There is a built in mechanism for protractor to run multiple instances of chrome for a given number of test suites. 
However two tests running in parallel can and will change common data causing one or both to fail.
My best bet at the moment is to use docker containers running the app with separate mongo dbs which I'm thinking is a pain to set up.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't be the answer you want, but... the trick to running parallel tests is to ALWAYS write your tests so they *can* be run in parallel. This means taking advantage of any and all strategies towards this goal, including using multiple users/accounts, and creating/deleting test data for each test. This also means tests cannot depend on other tests (coupling), which is a bad idea regardless of sharding.

The reason you *need* to do it up front is there are no situations where you *wouldn't* want your tests to run faster. And in addition to just sharding protractor tests, you may want to further increase test speed by *also* employing Docker containers in parallel.

Again... probably not what you want to hear, but...

Good luck!